# Discord bot not sending variables from outside

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord bot that streams the us election for fun
and I've got everything except it printing the points

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    global Biden
    global Trump
    while Biden > Trump:
        await ctx.send('Biden"s winning')
        await ctx.send('Trump, '.Trump)
        await ctx.send('Biden, '.Biden)
        time.sleep(5)
        if (Biden == 270):
            for i in (0, 5):
                await ctx.send('Biden WON')
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send('Trump"s winning')
        await ctx.send('Trump, '.Trump)
        await ctx.send('Biden, '.Biden)
        time.sleep(5)
        if (Trump == 270):
            for i in (0, 5):
                await ctx.send('Trump won')
                break
```

I just can't figure out how to make the bot send the two variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it including the fact that it wasn't updating the variables!

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):

    while 1 :
        Trumplists = soup.find('div', class_='ge-bar__count ge-bar__count--p color--R')
        Bidenlists = soup.find('div', class_='ge-bar__count ge-bar__count--p color--D')

        trumpstr = Trumplists.text.strip()
        bidenstr = Bidenlists.text.strip()

        Trump = int(trumpstr)
        Biden = int(bidenstr)
        if Biden > Trump:
            await ctx.send('')
            await ctx.send('Biden, ' + str(Biden))
            await ctx.send('Trump, '+ str(Trump))
            time.sleep(600)
            if (Biden == 270):
                for i in (0, 5):
                    await ctx.send('')
                break
        else:
            await ctx.send('')
            await ctx.send('Trump, '+ str(Trump))
            await ctx.send('Biden, '+ str(Biden))
            time.sleep(600)
            if (Trump == 270):
                for i in (0, 5):
                    await ctx.send('')
                    break
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`ctx.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) documentation, this method takes only one positional argument, a string, the message to send.

Replace

```py
await ctx.send('Trump, '.Trump)
await ctx.send('Biden, '.Biden)
```

with

```py
await ctx.send('Trump, ' + str(Trump))
await ctx.send('Biden, ' + str(Biden))
```

to make the string you want. Alternative methods to construct a string are the following:

```py
# f-strings
f"Trump, {Trump}"

# string formatting
"Trump, {}".format(Trump)

# string formatting with %
"Trump, %d" % Trump

# string concatenation
"Trump, " + str(Trump)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems. At first, you're not looping between 1-5, you're looping through a tuple. you have to use `range`.

And for formatting the string, you can use

`await ctx.send(f'Trump, {Trump}')` or

`await ctx.send('Trump, {0}'.format(Trump))`.

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    global Biden
    global Trump
    while Biden > Trump:
        await ctx.send('Biden"s winning')
        await ctx.send(f'Trump, {Trump}')
        await ctx.send(f'Biden, {Biden}')
        time.sleep(5)
        if Biden == 270:
            for i in range(0, 5):
                await ctx.send('Biden WON')
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send('Trump"s winning')
        await ctx.send(f'Trump, {Trump}')
        await ctx.send(f'Biden, {Biden}')
        time.sleep(5)
        if Trump == 270:
            for i in range(0, 5):
                await ctx.send('Trump won')
                break
```